# Query a C++ data structure from Web

Tags: javascript, php, c++, ajax

I have a HTML form input field and a submit button. I also have a C++ program which takes a graph and a query file. The C++ program runs on that graph file, builds a data structure(an index) and then use the query file to output results for all the queries in the file.

I have to enter a query in the input field and then use the C++ program on the server to answer my query. But if I do so, the C++ program will build the data structure (the index) again and again. Is there a way that I keep the index built and the queries which I enter in input field get answered by that index on server?

Comment: I have solved a similar problem by developing a persistant C++ daemon using the CppCMS library to expose HTTP REST functionality to handle an in-memory index. You might want to take a look at it to see if it can solve your problem.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like "listening for queries from the web portal" after the index is built? I'll have a look at the CppCMS library.

Comment: It is definitly possible if you can perform HTTP requests from the web portal, using something such as the PHP curl extension (I'm assuming your web portal is indeed in PHP).

Comment: But I will have to write the "listen to query" code in C++ right? even though the web portal is written in PHP? The flow: I write a query on web portal->It should go to the listener running in the C++ file after building the index -> Sends the result of query back to the web portal.

Comment: Well, you will have to write a minimal amount of code to handle HTTP requests in your C++ program, since much of the work is done very cleanly by the CppCMS library. It represents a really small amount of work compared to developing a server from scratch.